# iTextsharp HTML/CSS to pdf conversion. border-radius property not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, html-to-pdf

I have a requirement where I need to draw a circle with CSS. (Since the color of a circle is dynamic, so cannot use an image). Here is the code I am trying to get circle please help me if any workaround is there.

```
<div style="height: 10px;width: 10px;background-color: #bbb;border-radius: 50%;"></div>
```

c# code:

```
using (var htmlMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html)))
                {
                    using (var cssMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cssText)))
                    {
                        var a = XMLWorkerHelper.ParseToElementList(html, cssText);
                        XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, document, htmlMemoryStream, cssMemoryStream, Encoding.UTF8, FontFactory.FontImp, path);
                    }
                }
```

Note: cannot switch to other plugins

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this code:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;background-color: #9ca6b7;">
    <img style="width: 100% ;border-radius: 50%; height: 300px; width: 300px;" 
         src="https://i2.wp.com/beebom.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-2016.jpg?resize=640%2C426">
    </img>
</div>
```